# PRNG for ARM Assembly?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, random, arm

I'm having issues implementing a PRNG for ARM Assembly. I've tried a few algorithms that while working, end up taking a long time after the first few random number iterations, probably because the division (modulo) step takes a long time on large numbers. I'm trying to get a random number between 0 and 31. I've given my rough work below, with letters substituting specific registers.

start:

```
mov t, x            // t = x

// t ^= t << 11
lsl temp, t, #11
eor t, temp

// t ^= t >> 8
lsr temp, t, #8
eor t, temp

// z = w
mov z, w

// x = y
mov x, y

// y = z
mov y, z

// w ^= w >> 19
lsr temp, w, #19
eor w, temp

// w ^= t
eor w, t

// result is the RETURNED RANDOM NUMBER
mov result, w
```

That's my algorithm that I tried to implement from the XORSHIFT page on wikipedia. I just need this to return a random number from 0 to 31, so implementing division on a 10-digit number takes a while and seems pretty overkill. If anyone can help me optimize or point out a mistake I'd appreciate it.

edit: The above subroutine returns the random number, and then I basically divide it by 31 (that code isn't given here) and take the remainder as my "random" number from 0 to 31.

Comment: Your division is wrong; it should be "division by 32" to have a possible remainder of 31. But "modulo 32" is just "AND 31", keep the lower 5 bits.

Comment: Ah, using AND 31 cut the time down a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARM instructions [can shift or even rotate their inputs on the fly](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/barrel-shifter.html), so using separate left-shift instructions is a waste.  Apparently [in Thumb mode, only 32bit thumb instructions can use the barrel shifter](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473e/Babbfdic.html).

Note that if your routine is a function that you actually call, rather than just an inline snippet from a loop, then it doesn't follow the standard ABI.  That's fine if the only caller is also written by you in asm.  If you can dedicate 4 registers to PRNG state in your loop, then you don't need to pass pointers around or load/store.

As always, [compiler output](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:armhfg482,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-ffast-math++-fverbose-asm',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXO4MDoAWAfAFDEw4DMATAPoZIAeA9gE5r4gBmGNYTMABzgBDDAgAU5MBmp1GAGiRSZtegE9Fy2fQBemyqqQB3AJRIA3sSTWlBufQC8jANxWb9AHpP6KFEgCM/q42SJ7eSISESAAcwTYMSE5qzkhqiUg6KTrpRnHWRkhexhFR/gCcecVFGJUsCBgwLGDGrgC%2BpAD0HaFMSGgIyPhMBQC2wmBpI0wAbkjgmCwwEBggTGBoSMJ1m8swwlBQaWADiHDG%2BAjNANYDAuAA5n0YosjgSHX3aMRdxsjHCGdhEgoEwmAJcNYAPIYC4sIwgfq/JAAKxgmCQ93qwKYwjgaA6mFYCC%2BWkMzDYHG4NBBYMkdnoACp%2BBgBDAMPppNoFLZOYYNDyVHI9AKuaYLG5OKxxDg5g4AAxIFIgFD%2BOVqxVIADUmpAZksIVJ9nSDEqYVCqD8gVNhXCkRilQSSRSaScmQyOUqBSKBTt5U9NtClQZ4m1zNZGDMTlybna1jqDSaLWI7VICyW9HJ7C4PEwL3FBvp3P5wujrVcZELmcpGH8VGi4jTy0YrCzVNzYiQDLQerc1kN9EcfQAtIQTb3zdULQEguOzfQ7bFx2gR47h4RkmuXWu3cvCNknLvoyFDwGT76KkuR17vLV6o1moe2qRlAA2AAscir2dr0QEsDQdLSO%2Bchdj2ACQr4fhm6RoAA2nKAC6rgQTgwH0BAazolucH%2BEhxBgXBiHpMk%2BEJEUCS%2BEgVAUCkPzCPhOEIcahSpCx4gJL6ADsZgeEg4hpHaVAviYtHdAARooED4fG959LBuFaqkT6kBWQFQc2FLfnWf5otSoICIBgqMmGbKSZh9CQSB7YID2faoepcFUExTjmNZ8EIYobm4WW1g/CCED7E8eZoL0MLIDSAhIAF1y3HM9BvB8XzWJKLB8TKIDyhqyqquqKTarq%2BY2JZ0EHu5yHFVF5msaVuHIYRzlKaRAYUX41GiZsDHyQ1ZGsbx7ElAE3FsQJURCSJSA/BJUX4cGJkYNqkZyQpmpKb53TsPwUBnEYyBicghIsA8oQXEoAgCAgqXUGJSBMJwx3EggAD81gACJMMScVIGMGBiCwj0xm4MmJoxT5AAA%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) is often a good starting point:

```
// we need a loop to see how many mov instructions are actually needed when keeping state in regs
// Otherwise we just get loads/stores
uint32_t xorshift_loop(uint32_t *output, uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z, uint32_t w) {
  for(int i=0 ; i<1000 ; ++i) {
    uint32_t t = x;
    t ^= t << 11;
    t ^= t >> 8;
    x = y; y = z; z = w;
    w ^= w >> 19;
    w ^= t;
    *(++output) = w;
  }
  return w;
}
```

The inner loop is:

```
## 32bit ARM gcc 4.8  -O3 -fverbose-asm
## The @comments are from -fverbose-asm, which is more helpful than usual here
.L4:
        eor     r6, r1, r1, lsl #11       @, t, x, x,
        eor     r5, r4, r4, lsr #19       @, w, w, w,
        eors    r5, r5, r6                @, t, w, t
        mov     r1, r2                    @ x, y
        eor     r5, r5, r6, lsr #8        @, w, t, t,
        str     r5, [r0, #4]!     @ w, MEM[base: _42, offset: 4B]  // this is a post-increment store
        cmp     r0, r7    @ ivtmp.20, D.4237
        mov     r2, r3    @ y, z
        mov     r3, r4    @ z, w
        mov     r4, r5    @ w, w
        bne     .L4       @,
```

Notice how the XORs are reordered so the first couple instructions are part of separate dep chains.  That will help for superscalar in-order ARM cores, or if `eor` with a shifted operand has latency greater than 1.  It also chooses to do `w^=t; w^= t>>8` instead of `t^= t>>8; w^=t;`, but IDK if there's any particular advantage to that.

An unroll by two would get rid of all the `mov` instructions, leaving each iteration doing just the four `eor` instructions with shifted inputs per result.  It looks like gcc with `-funroll-loops` unrolls by 8, so the code is hard to follow.

---

[`xorshift+` is apparently pretty good quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift.2B) for something that's so fast.

It compiles to short code on AArch64, and still short/efficient-looking code on 32bit ARM.  Much more code than just xorshift, though.  See my godbolt compiler explorer link above

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! The in-line shifting/rotating made my code a lot cleaner. Great answer.